Unable to create a 'DbContext' in MySql - Blazor .NET 9
I'm trying to connect Blazor (.NET 9) to a MySql database (8.4.3). I've read a lot of posts and tried different packages without success.
Here are the packages I've installed:
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="9.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="9.0.0">
        <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="9.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="9.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="8.0.2" />
</ItemGroup>

Here is the appsettings.json file:
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=x.x.x.x;Database=DB_Cours;User=UserCours;Password=12345678"
},

Here is Program.cs:
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<MySqlDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseMySql(connectionString, new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8,4,3))));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

This is my MySqlDbContext.cs:
public class MySqlDbContext(DbContextOptions<MySqlDbContext> options) : DbContext(options)
{
    public DbSet<Person>? Person { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasData(
            new Person { Id = 1, Name = "Laurent"},
            new Person { Id = 2, Name = "John"},
            new Person { Id = 3, Name = "Mike" },
            new Person { Id = 4, Name = "Larry" }
        );
    }
}

When I'm doing the migration by taping Add-Migration Init I'm getting this error message:

Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type 'RuntimeType'.
The exception 'Method 'get_LockReleaseBehavior' in type 'Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Migrations.Internal.MySqlHistoryRepository' from assembly 'Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql, Version=8.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2cc498582444921b' does not have an implementation.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance.

As I explained I've tried other packages, downgrade versions, and nothing works.
I appreciate your help

Well, it is a package version problem.
If we read the documentation Pomelo GitHub, we can see that ".Net9" works only with preview vs: 9.0.0-preview.2.efcore.9.0.0 package.
